# Remove hardcoded WHERE (true) from sql statement in order to append AND dynamically

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, .net-core, ado.net

We are using quite a lot kind of pattern for SQL server table lookups  like this one bellow:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder($"SELECT * FROM {tableName} WHERE 1=1");
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(queryObj?.StudentName))
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(" AND StudentName=@StudentName");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentName", queryObj.StudentName);
            if (queryObj?.StudentTeacher != null)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(" AND StudentTeacher=@StudentTeacher");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentTeacher", queryObj.StudentTeacher);
            }
            else
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(" AND StudentTeacher IS NULL");
            }
        }
        cmd.CommandText = stringBuilder.ToString();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();

    ========== code ommited for brevity ===========
        
    }
```

It is obvious that we have condition `WHERE 1=1` (and it is really nasty IMHO and moreover you can imagine what could happen if for some reason AND(s) don't exist and table has billion of records) in order to narrow filters depending on other conditions.

Is there some better approach for appending additional `AND` filters and how to avoid `WHERE 1=1` and still be able to construct appropriate queries with additional filters?

Comment: How can you not know the name of the table you are querying? I would suggest not using AddWithValue. It can do some really funky things. https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/

Comment: If you would omit the where 1=1 you will still have the same problem when an AND does not exists, or am I wrong here ? That is assuming you have some logic that puts "where" when you have noting yet, and "and" after that

Comment: For the topic at hand that 1=1 is just a way to avoid having to check for each additional predicate. Removing that isn't going to make any difference because it would be the same thing as not adding a where clause at all.

Comment: @GuidoG Let's suppose I have a guard that will ensure ANDs are always passed in

Comment: Even with your guard, the problem will remain the same, with or without the  where 1=1

Comment: Put you conditions in a string list. Do a string.join with AND as separator and put a WHERE in front if needed.

Comment: @SeanLange not exactly if I omit 1=1 than in the end my sql will be something like this: 
SELECT * FROM {tableName} WHERE AND StudentTeacher='Marry' which is incorrect

Comment: LOL right....that was my point. You asked about removing it because it could cause performance problems. I said the reason it is there is so you don't have to check if you already have a where predicate when adding additional ones. I would just leave it be since it is already working.

Comment: I disagree that `WHERE 1 = 1` is "really nasty" - it's just like stuffing the first comma in a comma-separated list, you have to deal with 0 or more conditionals _somehow_ (I do a similar thing [here](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example)), the other option being only add `WHERE` if conditional.count > 0. Also, additional info about `AddWithValue()`: [Can we stop using `AddWithValue()` already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @AaronBertrand It reminds me on SQL injection :D

Comment: @SeanLange tableName is predefined (code ommited for brevity)

Comment: I don't see the link with sql injection here, what doe you mean @BranimirBzenić ?